# Query multiple tables and if, elseif, else condition

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to show different messages/button based on query returns. There are 3 different situations.

1. User review his account
2. User review friend account
3. User review non-friend account

So when user check his own account I hide the button "add as friend". When he check non-friend account I show button "add as friend". When user check friend account I want to show message that this user is his friend.

This is the query and the if, elseif, else condition. The logic is something wrong but can't figured it out what exactly.

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])){
      $id = $_GET['id']; {     
$result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT usr.*, userFriends.*
                         FROM users usr
                            LEFT JOIN user_friends userFriends
                                ON usr.id = userFriends.friend_id
                         WHERE id = ?                           
                         LIMIT 1");

    $result -> bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $result -> execute();
    foreach ( $result as $row )
    {
         // some html here
        if($_SESSION['id'] == $row['user_id'])
        { 
            echo ''; 
        } 
        elseif ($id == $row['friend_id'])
        {
            echo ' Already friends ';
        }
        else                            
        { 
            echo ' Add as friend '; 
        }
    }
 }
```

So `$_SESSION['id']` is current ( logged user ).

`$id` is non-friend/friend profile

`$row['user_id']` is current user from table `user_friends`

`$row['friend_id']` is non-friend/friend id from `user_friends` table

Comment: Can you copy the result of var_dump($result); please ?

Comment: It is the same as the query.

Comment: then can you print the value of $row ? if your cases aren't working as intended the problem must be there also I've just figured out, that your checking user_id on the first if then friend_id, is that intended ?

Comment: Now I got on friend button is hidden. On current user is message that "already firends". On the non-friend button is hidden and no messages.

Comment: Yes, because on `IF` I check on the page when is current user profile. `elseif` i want to check if they are already friends i.e. on friend user page. `else` is when is non-friend page

Comment: $id = $_GET['id']; **{**  <---- extra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic abit wrong..

what you want to check? you want to check if $id is $_SESSION['id']'s friend.. so you should select based on $id or $_SESSION['id'] ?

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])){
   //the first thing you need to check is that is this you are viewing your own profile by just checking this and without even need to query.
   if($_SESSION['id'] == $_GET['id']){
      echo '';
   } else {
       $id = $_GET['id'];

       $result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT usr.*, userFriends.*
                     FROM users usr
                        LEFT JOIN user_friends userFriends
                            ON usr.id = userFriends.friend_id
                     WHERE **Your ID Column**= ?                           
                     LIMIT 1");

      $result -> bindParam(1, $_SESSION['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
      $result -> execute();
      //check if the result return rows?
      // if return rows of data, it's already friend
      // else its not friend yet

      // what's the purpose for this loop then?
      foreach ( $result as $row ){

      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic in query is a bit wrong.

First you need both `id`: `user_id` and `friend_id`.

Since `$id = $_GET['id'];` I guess `$id` var keeps `friend_id` (the id of profile user try to view).

But you need to get current `user_id` somehow.

Like `$user_id = $_SESSION['id'];`

And then:

```
SELECT u.id user_id, uf.frien_id
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN user_friends uf
ON u.id = uf.user_id
   AND  uf.friend_id = ?                           
WHERE u.id = ?
LIMIT 1

...

$result -> bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$result -> bindParam(1, $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Do you really have a record in `user_friends` where `user_id = friend_id`? Usually I don't. So if there is no such record.

So you have to change your condition `if($_SESSION['id'] == $row['user_id'])` to

```
if($id == $user_id)
```

Comment: Current user ( logged user ) is `$_SESSION['id']`

Comment: Like this I got same profile on every user .. because of $_SESSION['id'] i guess.

Comment: Beacuse you did not filtered your user_friends table by current user, but just by friend_id, so query succeed if this porfile owner is a friend of **any** user